# Does failing `require` makes function use less or no GAS

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Let's imagine simple smart contract function

```
mapping (address => uint8) votes;
function vote(address _address, uint8 _vote) {
   require(notVotedYet(_address))
   votes[_address] = _vote
}
```

I know to make a method free - I should mark it as `view`, but this doesn't fit.

This method writes to the blockchain only if the user hasn't cast his vote yet.

My questions are:

1. would EVM "know" that there can be a require failing, and make such
   calls free? Or in other words **would gas "consumption" be different when the require fails and when it pass?**
2. If not (the gas consumed is constant) - is there a way to implement it (with
   modifiers?) so any call from `_address` would not cost any GAS?

I gues my main question would be: is gas consumption calculated during runtime, or by some kind of static analysic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. would EVM "know" that there can be a require failing, and make such calls free?

If the visibility of your function is set to `view` it will be either way free.

In case there is `require` in your method and it failes, the returned value will be:

- **0** for `uint`
- **false** for `bool`
- **0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000** for `address`
- "" for `string`

In your case line `votes[_address] = _vote` is modifiying the state. And modifiying the state always costs gas. If you add new non-zero value it will take 20000 gas, if you will set this value to 0 it will cost 5000 gas. This operation is called `SSTORE` on lower level. It illustrates that you make changes in storage memory.

---

> would gas "consumption" be different when the require fails and when
>   it pass?

The idea is, tx sender pays for any computation done by miner. In case of `require`, miner will be rewarded for work which he did **anyway**. `21000 gas` will cover the cost of an elliptic curve operation to recover the sender address from the signature **+** any gas consumed by computations before `require`.

All the remaining gas (`gasLimit - gasConsumed`) will be sent back to tx sender in case of `REVERT` opcode which is being triggered when `require` evaluates to **false**. All **require-style** exceptions follow this behavior.

*In case of **assert-style** exception, full `gasLimit` will be consumed by failed transaction.*

---

The Byzantium (Metropolis part 1 - released in October, 2017) change mentioned in the docs is that `require` now uses the `REVERT` opcode. Prior to the release, it used the same opcode as `assert`, which would consume all gas. `REVERT` refunds the remaining gas. See this blog post for detailed information: [POST](https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e)

Comment: You're talking about returned values, but my question was different: in the case where I call the function, and require fails - would it cost any gas?

Comment: @meta yes. It will cost gas spent on computations before the require exception was raised.

Comment: @meta so the unspent gas limit will be returned back to the sender. In case of `assert` it will consume all the gas limit provided if `assert` return false.

Comment: I think you made a mistake (or maybe talking about an older version of Ethereum) - I found the docs stating that `require` failing returns all the gas. Please check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720721/299774

Answer (score 0):

Edit: So the documentation is not really precise, and by "consuming no gas" it apparently means consuming only used gas, not all gas limit.

I don't know why it is like that, but I noticed on the Udemy course that the presenter also says "no gas consumed" when you clearly can see few thousand gas spent. And where there's few orders or magnitude spent - it's considered "really spent"

It's a bit confusing. Please check the [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48719651/299774) too.

---

So I scanned the docs, and found a clear answer:

> Note that assert-style exceptions consume all gas available to the call, while require-style exceptions will not consume any gas starting from the Metropolis release.

source: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

I couldn't find exact date, but based on various articles it looks like it has been released already (https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/the-ethereum-releases-of-frontier-homestead-metropolis-and-serenity/)

Comment: Here is transaction in Ropsten which raised require-style exception in smart contract: [tx](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xaf476e8278a10d2bc6fecdf3138432ad6d8d20687de3bcc3f160a81ed53b2f2e). You can clearly see the consumed amount of gas and the price in Ropsten ETH for its execution (even with revert opcode).

Comment: I can't understand the opcode yet, so I have to trust you on this one. But what does it mean? The docs are incorrect or the transaction was run on the Ethereum version from before `Metropolis` release? Or something else even?

Comment: I ran this transaction today for example. You can see the same gas consumptions on etherscan on a mainnet. Docs are correct, they can be a little ambiguous thou. The idea is, tx sender pays for any computation done by miner. In case of `require` miner will be rewarded for work which he did. 21000 gas will cover the cost of an elliptic curve operation to recover the sender address from the signature + any gas consumed by computations before `require`.

Comment: And all the remaining gas (`gasLimit` - `gasConsumed`) will be sent back to tx sender in case of `require`.

Comment: Roman's answer is correct. The Byzantium (Metropolis part 1 - released in October, 2017) change mentioned in the docs is that `require` now uses the REVERT opcode. Prior to the release, it used the same opcode as `assert`, which would consume all gas. REVERT refunds the remaining gas. See this blog post for detailed information: https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e

Comment: I get it now. @RomanFrolov would you update your answer? Those comments here make it more clear. I will be happy to accept it then.

Comment: @meta I've made the edit, hope the answer is more clear now.